# Vim - command - T

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, vim, fuzzyfinder

I have made the move from TextMate to VIM.  I can not use macvim, policy at work does not allow me to install it.  I have tried installing command-t to give me "go to file" functionality.  However as I am using VIM with the osx terminal, when I press command-t it opens a new tab.

I have now decided to try FuzzyFinder but can not figure out how to search across a directory recursively for a file with it, could anyone show me how to go to a file like command-t but using FuzzyFinder. :-/

Comment: Did you try to install MacVim in `~/Applications`? The policies at my work are quite restrictive but this location is safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command-T describes its intended use inside MacVim. If you want to use it inside terminal Vim, use the default binding `<Leader>t` (by default, `<Leader>` is the backslash key). You can remap this in your Vim config if you'd rather use a modifier key binding.

Comment: Remapping `<leader>` is done by adding this line to `~/.vimrc`: `let mapleader="<your key here>"`.

Answer (score 3):

Fuzzy finder is not under active development. You're way better off with the awesome Command-t. The problem is terminal Vim does support it because terminal Vim needs to be built with Ruby support. It's fairly straightforward to build Vim from source to enable this.

http://brilliantcorners.org/2011/02/building-vim-on-osx-snow-leopard/

Guide for Snow Leopard but works for Lion too. You'll need to have XCode installed, not just the GCC compiler.

Comment: Since writing this, I've discovered that you can actually run MacVim through the terminal with `mvim -v`. MacVim's build includes Ruby so this is a far better solution than building your own from source. You can also install MacVim with `brew install macvim`.

Answer (score 1):

You could map it to `ctrl` or `shift` easily, which won't conflict with your OS like `command`, via:

```
nmap <C-t> :CommandT<CR>

# or

nmap T :CommandT<CR>
```

In normal fuzzyfinder to search through a directory you can use file globs, like `**`, e.g., at the fuzzyfinder prompt:

```
>File>**/yourpattern
```

Will search all directories under the current directory for your pattern.  Just be wary not to try to do that on large filesystems, or you're going to be waiting a while and/or running out of memory.  It will index the tree in memory after the first search though, and will be faster afterwards.